# Matplotlib - x axis does not match the data

Tags: matplotlib, axis

The description of the data frame

[image]

When I try to find the relationship between budget and revenue_of_investment

```
x = dfm_2.budget
y = dfm_2.revenue_of_investment
plt.figure(figsize = (10,8))
plt.xlim((40000,42500000))
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

The output is:

[image]

I know the range of the budget is big, but I do not figure out the data on the x-axis.
I even set the range, however, the x-axis doesn't fit the data.

Comment: Sorry but it seems like your question was cut off there at the end, the post ends in 'I even set the range, ho'. Can you check and revise ?

Comment: Is your issue that not all of the data fit in the plot ?

Comment: Are you just missing that the `1e7` in the bottom right corner is a multiplier for values on the x axis?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly (i.e. that the plot is not displaying all of the data on the x-axis), it's because your upper xlim is too small.

The maximum value of dfm_2.budget is 4.25 * 1e8 (i.e. 425000000), but your xlim upper limit is set to 4.25 * 1e7 (i.e. 42500000) (i.e. you're missing a zero in your plt.xlim())

Comment: ok! I edited that. But is there a way to show the data as 425000000 instead of 4.25*1e8?